# when starting browser using proxychains i m getting the error below, please anyone help me on this

Tags: kali-linux, firefox, proxychains

```
root@kali:/home/fake# proxychains firefox www.duckduckgo.com
[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.4
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($XAUTHORITY is /home/fake/.Xauthority which is owned by fake.)
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it about using software in a way it is not intended to be.

Answer (score 2):

> Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.

The error message is clear: do not run Firefox as root, login as normal user and re-run the command.

Also if you are new to Linux, I highly suggest starting with a different more user friendly distribution like Ubuntu, Mint or Fedora, not Kali Linux. You can use all the tools on these and it will be way easier.